# Compare string to a row in a table

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a table in my database called "admin".

```
AdminID Login         Password 

1       Admin         123 

2       Administrator 321
```

When I complete my authorization, I want to check an entire table for matches.

```
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "select login, password from admin");
    $AdminArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 
    if ($_SESSION[ 'login' ] === $AdminArr[ 'login' ] && $_SESSION[ 'password' ] === $AdminArr[ 'password' ])
    {
       header("Location:admin.php");
       $auth = true;
    }
```

As of right now only first row is displayed. I need to check if my authorization data matches with other table data. So that if I login with "administrator" and "321" it also logins me as an admin.
I'm probably overcomplicating everything but that's my first time working with sessions & admin panel. 
 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the code shown, nothing would be displayed.

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text. Use a `where` clause.

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough as to how unsafe this all is.

Comment: @chris85 Right you are, not to mention in a session array, *wow*.

Comment: so, what do you get back when you `var_dump()` the whole thing?

Comment: Last ditch effort. When you add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `mysqli_error($link)` to the query, what does it show you, or have you logged off? We/I are trying to help, but there's no word from you.

Comment: *"As of right now only first row is displayed."* - I don't see where you're echoing anything.

Comment: I'm going to mark this question as unclear and then just move on.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not as experienced with php, still a lot to learn. I just pasted some code, it's not all of it. I'm going to try with where clause, I was originally thinking I might have same names. I could paste my entire php code but it's quite messy as of right now because of all comments from testing

Comment: try using prepared statements, hash you pass with  PASSWORD_BCRYPT, and set your session results from the query then do the if statement